# How I can join compiled jasper file and my project in java?

Tags: java

I have design my project in iReport and I have compiled successfully. Now I want to add the compiled jasper file to add in my java project. May any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just add them in some package in your source tree. Your build process or IDE should copy them in your classes directory or in the generated jar file, along with your classes. The reports may then be loaded with [`Class.getResource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need in order to get two values from two combo-boxes, add them to a HashMap and pass the map to iReport. These paramaters, for this example "**storeName**" and "**actionCode**", are used to specify values for the query which is stored inside the iReport. The report jasper file is "**../ireps/AccessCounter.jrxml**". The viewer is  a JDialog. If you have no parameters to pass to your report just skip the map.put. con is the connection to the database.

Make sure that you include the necessary jar file to your path.

```
try {
    String shopName = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String actionCode = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("storeName", shopName);
    map.put("actionCode", actionCode);

    URL reportFileURL = getClass().getResource("../ireps/AccessCounter.jrxml");
    File reportFile = new File(reportFileURL.toURI());
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportFile);
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map, con);
    JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
    JDialog viewer = new JDialog(this, "Batch Report", true);
    viewer.setBounds(jv.getBounds());
    viewer.getContentPane().add(jv.getContentPane());
    viewer.setResizable(true);
    viewer.setIconImage(jv.getIconImage());
    viewer.setVisible(true);
} catch (JRException exc) {
   System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
} catch (URISyntaxException exs) {
   System.out.println(exs.getMessage());
}
```